# Is there a Unicode "white space" character that is exempt from trimming?

Tags: c#, unicode, windows-runtime, uwp

I am using context menu based on [PopupMenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.popups.popupmenu) class with menu commands added with **UICommand** class. Everything works fine but trying to add a check-mark for a command currently selected. This is also easy by using a suitable Unicode char such as a check-mark or solid circle, etc.

The tricky bit is that, to align the commands, I needed to insert a 'white space' at the beginning of each command without a check-mark, so that the command texts are all aligned, with a check-mark offset to the left (such example [here](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/make-menu-items-act-like-radio-buttons-in-c/) just for visual illustration). Every attempt made to insert space chars, the leading white spaces are always get trimmed.

Now, that got me thinking: if there is a Unicode white space character that a WinRT/UWP system exempts from trimming and treat such char as is (as a white space character).

I have come across special cases such as **non-breaking** space char. By the same token, is there a *non-trimmable* space char?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `MenuFlyout` instead, which is more commonly used. It also allows you to use `MenuFlyoutItems`, which you can retemplate by putting whatever layout you'd like in them.

Comment: +1 Thanks, that's a better solution. I was trying to keep an existing code based on PopupMenu but it has very limited styling options, most importantly a built-in option for check-mark which MenuFlyout (and a sub-class ToggleMenuFlyout) support with more options.